# Trouble importing a .dat file in R with uneven columns

Tags: r

I am trying to copy a .dat file as a data frame. The data file is a FIM repository file retrieved from  [T10I4D100K.dat](http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/T10I4D100K.dat)

As you can see the data file has uneven columns, and i am trying to read it as follows :

fimd <- read.table("T10I4D100K.dat", header=FALSE)

i am getting an error as 
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 16 elements

Am i getting this error because of the uneven entries in the file?
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add argument `fill=T`, so R will fill missing observations with NA's.